# How to convert group column values to a nested list column in R

Tags: r

Data example:

| Contig | Taxa |
| --- | --- |
| contig_1 | Yersinia phage phiR1-37 |
| contig_1 | NA |
| contig_1 | Yellowstone lake phycodnavirus 1 |
| contig_2 | Xylella phage Salvo |
| contig_2 | NA |

Desired output:

| Contig | Taxa |
| --- | --- |
| contig_1 | Yersinia phage phiR1-37 |
| contig_1 | Yellowstone lake phycodnavirus 1, Xylella phage Salvo |

Is there a more efficient/eloquent way to do this in R than:

```
my_dict<-list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df$Contig)){
  contig_val<-df$Contig[i]
  my_dict[[contig_val]]<- c(df$taxa[df$Contig==contig_val])
  print(my_dict)
}

$NODE_2010_length_6628_cov_7.78396
[1] "Gordonia phage Gmala1"       NA                            "Klebsiella phage SopranoGao"

$NODE_2011_length_6620_cov_6.50952
[1] NA                          "Streptococcus phage 315.5" "Leptospira phage LE4"
```

How do I write this list as a column value?

Comment: You need to share a reproducible sample of your data with `dput(head(data))` so that others can use it to help you.

Comment: Looks like you might want `my_dict = with(df, split(taxa, Contig))`, but without reproducible input it's hard to tell.

Comment: FYI, two minor things about the R code here: (1) `NROW(df$Contig)` is not returning the number of rows in a column, it's returning the length of the vector. If you want the number of rows in the frame, use `nrow(df)`. (2) `1:nrow(.)` works fine, but in other scenarios where one has "empty data" and expects the `for` loop to do nothing, this will fail since `1:nrow(df)` with 0 rows resolves to `1:0` aka `c(1, 0)` which executes the loop twice. It's better to use `for (i in seq_len(nrow(df)))` for a more robust loop, where if `df` has 0 rows then nothing will be done (as intended).

Comment: Thanks very much. I have updated to include an example.